# Show that the solutions to DE constitute a solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I use the solutions to show that they constitute a solution space?

[image]

Comment: Can you define "solution space"? I think I know what it means but this particular usage seems to be nonstandard.

Comment: @Ian that is what I am having problems with I don't understand part a. Can you give it a try using the definition you know?

Comment: I think your text is defining a "solution space" to be a vector space consisting entirely of solutions to the equation. Thus you would need to show that if $y_1,y_2$ are solutions and $c_1,c_2$ are real numbers then $c_1 y_1+c_2 y_2$ is also a solution.